Linked share option is always picking up home page as a preview link - Linkedin post inspector also showing wrong canonical link
When I share a job details page link in linkedin, it is always picking up homepage as a preview link.
I tested the same link in "Linkedin Post Instector - https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/". Canonical link in the post-inspector is always showing the home page instead of job details page.
I added correct og:url tag to all the pages. Still it dint worked.
I tried adding correct rel=canonical and tried removing it from all pages. Still linkedin post instspector is picking up home page as a canonical url.
Can anyone please assist how the linkedin share works? How the linkedin post inspector picking the wrong canonical url?
Example urls:
https://philadelphia.pt/receitas/po-com-philadelphia-gro-de-429888/
https://www.mondelezinternational.com/careers/jobs/job?jobid=R-125228&jobtitle=Brand+Manager,+Cadbury


